# How to specify which redis installation to use?

Tags: redis, anaconda

I just installed redis-server in my machine but my machine keeps on picking redis installed from anaconda package. When I do

```
which redis-server
```

I get

```
/anaconda/bin/redis-server
```

When  I want the installation directory of redis. Is there any way to specify which one pick, when I write redis-server?

Answer (score 0):

A dumb solution is to remove anaconda-redis by
`conda uninstall redis`
then install your redis
if you want to bring anaconda-redis back, use
`conda install redis`
but 2.6.9 is a little old...